# Why does this array allocation cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create an array of vectors of ints, but I'm getting a segfault in this code.

```
int main() {
    vector<int> x[1000000];
}
```

I assumed this was because I was exceeding the stack size, so I used dynamic allocation and it seemed to solve the problem.  However, why does this work:

```
vector<int> x[1000000];

int main() {
    // do nothing
}
```

and this work?

```
int main() {
    static vector<int> x[1000000];
}
```

Comment: It's because the variable gets allocated on the data segment, not on the stack

Comment: So global and static variables are always allocated on the heap?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://static.duartes.org/img/blogPosts/linuxFlexibleAddressSpaceLayout.png) image of a program anatomy. In your first implementation, the memory is allocated on the stack, which according to the picture, has a limit of 8MB (different machine might have different limit). The data segment is larger than 8MB and therefore, no errors are thrown when trying to allocate such vector

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I wasn't aware that there were other accessible memory spaces than the stack and the heap.

Comment: I'm just curious about why you need one million vectors.

Comment: It's an adjacency list that I'm DFSing through.

Comment: It's a mistake to believe that the stack and heap are the only places variables can be assigned. Static variables can occupy a third place.

Comment: @CSGregorian "stack" and "heap" are implementation details. In standard C++ there are four storage types: *automatic*, *static*, *dynamic*, and *thread*.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, and so is segfault too. I don't know if/where the standards provides for a limited stack, but I suspect that it would consider it "undefined behavior" if too much stack is being used.

Comment: The standard assumes there is unlimited 'stack' space . Technically the implementation is non-conforming if it encounters a stack overflow but we don't focus too much on the nitty gritty there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the array is allocated on the stack in the first example and your implementation imposes a too tight limit on the available stack. Your second example might have succeeded by pure luck.

Refer to [this picture](http://static.duartes.org/img/blogPosts/linuxFlexibleAddressSpaceLayout.png) on a normal layout of the memory of your program, accessing white areas may result in segmentation errors (and are otherwise a bad idea anyway).

Now when you allocate a non-static local variable the direct data will be allocated on the stack, but the constructor can also allocate space on the heap via `new`. In your case the constructor will probably allocate memory as well (the direct data for `vector` might be as little as a pointer, but you allocate a million of them so that's at least 8Mb of direct data). It may be the existence of the constructor that actually makes your program segfault as the space allocated on the stack otherwise might be unaccessed (it's when you actually accesses the space outside the stack limit you will get a segfault).

When you allocate static or global data the direct data is allocated in the data or BSS segment instead, if the prelaunch data (ie the data before the constructor is run if any) is zero it will be placed in the BSS segment. In your case it's likely that the data will be placed in BSS.

Note now that with global allocation the constructor will run before you reach main (as opposed to static that will not run until the function is called for the first time), but as you may have dynamically allocation via `new` in the constructor and calling `new` before main means undefined behavior you should consider youself lucky that the second example didn't fail (it could do so without prior notice).

The lesson to learn from this is that you better put large data in global scope only if it doesn't need a complex constructor. If you need a complex constructor you better dynamically allocate it via `new`. You could of course put it in as local `static` and return a reference to the object if you need it globally.